# How do I set the the appropriate Character encoding in a HTTP response to support European Characters like Ú

Tags: java, servlets, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a servlet, and I don't set any charset. European characters are coming through as non-printable in the browser when the servlet responds. Will using UTF-8 charset encoding in the response header make the browser interpret these characters correctly, or should I use a different encoding ?

Is the a code-snippet, below, correct when used in the http response class ?

```
setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: Why  did you decide that you need a character set superior to utf-8? Iso8859-1 is definitely less capable (it contains symbols only for few western European languages, even eastern European countries with based on Latin alphabet have to use char sets other than iso8859-1

Comment: this is my quandry, I don't know which is a superior character encoding to UTF-8 that also supports European characters...

Comment: There is nothing superior to UTF-8 (in this context), and your real problems are due to something else.  This whole question is based on a fundamental misunderstanding of Unicode and UTF-8.

Comment: @guilo - still wrong.  UTF-8 >>does<< support European characters.

Comment: Major question change..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that [this](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-return-the-content-in-the-correct-encoding-from-a-servlet/211) link addresses the problem. You need to define a charset in the response header for content-type. It can be done a couple of ways. To paraphrase the response in the link

"....
Example I

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    …
    String xml = "some xml";
    resp.setContentType("text/xml");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.write(xml); }
```

When the content contains some non-ascii characters, you need to make sure the they are in the correct encoding, otherwise the requester will get non displayable characters. There are two ways to do it. The first one is to call the setCharacterEncoding(encodingOfYourChoice) of the HttpServletResponse.

Example II

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    …
    String xml = "some xml";
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resp.setContentType("text/xml");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.write(xml); }
```

The other way is to add the charset property in the content type:

Example III

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    …
    String xml = "some xml";
    resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.write(xml); }
```

Note, both calls in example II and III need to be called before the getWriter() method. Once the getWriter() method is called, the charset can't be changed. When setting the contentType without the charset property, the OS's default charset will be used, such as ISO-8859-4.

..."

Answer (score 3):

> Is the a code-snippet, below, correct when used in the http response class ?

```
    setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

Simply, yes it is correct.

Assuming (of course) that the HTML is properly UTF-8 encoded ...

Just make sure that you do that before the response is "committed".

Comment: Your original answer, (below), is no longer applicable you may want to remove it and leave this one instead. If you think the current question is applicable, then you should un-downvote, as I have already done for your original answer....

Comment: @guilio - it is applicable to people who want to read the history of your question.  What you have done ... rewriting a Question to totally change its meaning ... is often considered to be "bad behaviour" here.

Comment: I don't think readers will care about the mis-interpretation. They want clean, concise answers.. But it's your choice.. I have "un-downvoted" your original answer, if my updated question is now applicable based on your most recent answer, I would appreciate you "un-downvoting" the question to..

Comment: Sorry.  The answer is still no.

Answer (score 1):

This answer relates to the original Question and numerous updates ... prior to the final "rewrite".

> However, European countries use the extended character sets for obscure characters that are outside the specified range for UTF-8. I know this is a common problem.

Also restated as:

> However, European countries use character encodings to support characters not supported in UTF-8.

BOTH of these are incorrect from two respects.

1. UTF-8 is not a character set.  It is a character *encoding*, and it encodes the *entire* Unicode code space.
2. There are no "obscure characters" that are commonly used in European countries that do not have corresponding Unicode code points, and therefore cannot be encoded in UTF-8.

And this:

> However, European countries use character encodings not supported in UTF-8.

This is just plain nonsensical.  It makes no sense to talk about character encodings not supported in other character encodings.  Each encoding is distinct, and any overlap of their bit patterns is ... an artefact of their respective histories.  (You don't seem to understand the difference between a code point aka character, and an encoding.)

And even ignoring these issues, you are still trying to say that there are European characters that UTF-8 does not handle with ... which is simply FALSE, no matter how you try to say it.

---

In short, your question is based on misconceptions, and therefore cannot be answered ... apart from pointing out the misconceptions.

The problems you are seeing are most likely caused by either:

- a bug in the way you are handling the data upstream of the rendering to HTML,
- a mismatch between the data you are sending and the content type you are using, or
- browsers that are incapable of displaying glyphs that correspond to the characters that you are using.

Probably one of the first two ...

---

If you think I'm "talking rubbish", please provide specific examples of the characters that you are talking about.

Comment: Your response is valuable, but it's not really an answer, more of a comment. I am adjusting my question as per your initial response.

Comment: I don't think you're talking rubbish, although you are being "prickly". You are requesting clarifications, and they are valid. Also, I can see you've requested the question be closed (?). A bit premature don't you think ? I have updated the question.

Comment: Given that your "clarification" is just as wrong as the original, no I don't think it was premature!!  As I said, provide me an example of a European character that is not in UTF-8 / Unicode.

Comment: Problem is I don't know which character set is being used. I do know it's European, but not which character set for instance,this one => Ú

Comment: Well, you can sit there all day and pick apart what's wrong with it, or you can help clarify the question as you can see I have an encoding issue and want to use an appropriate encoding charset....

Comment: The Unicode code for that character is U+00DA - and the UTF-8 encoding is C3 9A.  UTF-8 will clearly encode that character.  We can't help you solve yout problem unless you explain *how* you are treating your data.

Comment: Alright now we're getting somewhere, does this mean it can be supported by UTF-8 ?

Comment: Absolutely.  You are FINALLY getting the message!!!

Comment: I just checked the http response and now NO charset is specified in the content-type. This should be charset=UTF-8; then ?

Comment: If you are sending UTF-8 encoded data in the response, then yes the content type should specify that.  (IIRC, Latin-1 is assumed by a web browser if the character encoding is not specified in the content type or the HTML document itself.)

Comment: But I don't know why I'm continuing to help you ... given the downvote on my Answer.  Anyway, I've got *real* work to do now.

Comment: You're very quick to dismiss the questions early in the questions life through discussion. Gotta hold off that trigger Tex....I can re-word the question and you can answer it, and you'll get the points for it, or we both lose.. what would you like to do ?

Comment: I suggest you delete the question.  It doesn't have any bearing on whatever your real problem is.  Any further attempts to "fix" the question would be a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: You may want to delete your answer now.. as you've provided an alternative...

Comment: I don't want to.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Iso8859-1 is a byte oriented encoding which contains exactly 256 symbols (255 in fact, 'cause 0th is no-op and widely used as string terminator). Lower 128 is standard ASCII set and upper 128 are diacritics letters and various funny symbols like British pound sign (#163). Since iso8859-1 is so limited and even not suitable for certain European languages, there are iso8859-2, -3 and so on. AFAIR iso8859-15 was invented mainly for the Euro sign.

Unlike iso8859 encodings which are 256 bytes long, Utf-8 is a byte-oriented encoding in which symbols may take a variable number of bytes. Usual ASCII (which stands for American Standard code for for Information interchange) symbols take one byte exactly and coincide which ASCII. Latin diacritics and such symbols as Cyrillic and Greek alphabets take AFAIR 2 bytes per symbol and so on up to 5 bytes currently. The exact coding is described on the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8. Thus this encoding may incude virtually all existing alphabets and other symbols on the planet (of course it depends on exact revision of UTF-8, 'cause it's extendable by its nature).

But if you need to perform extensive string operations (collating, extracting parts etc) then you may consider to use a so called wide character encoding. Such an encoding (e.g. UCS-2 or ISO10646-1) uses a fixed number of bytes per character, usually 2 or 4. Most european symbols in such encodings have their upper part equals to 0, that's why you often got `<smth>\0<smth>\0<smth>\0`... when you look at bytes sequences in files written in Windows for example. But their capacity is less or equal to the capacity of UTF-8.

UTF-8 is widely used in data interchanging in Internet because most internet protocols are byte-oriented. Thus you may internally work with wide characters (the type `wchar_t` in C/C++, `java.util.String`, Python `unicode` strings and so on) and encode these strings to UTF-8 when you need to pass the data outside